# Is it a good idea to use COLUMN AS (left([Another_Column],(4)) instead of LEFT in the select?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I came across a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1
(
 CD1    int
,CD2    varchar(16)
,CD3    varchar(21)
,CD4    decimal(14,0)
,CD5    varchar(4)
,CD6    decimal(18,2)
,CD7    AS (left([CD3],(4)))
)
```

This table has more than 4 BILLION rows (totally unnecessary, but this is another topic).

As you can see in the last column, they use `AS (left([CD3],(4)))`. I think this is pretty useless, since we almost NEVER have a SELECT on this table, and here is just using space.

Isn't it better to select that field during the select when needed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the computed column isn't persisted or indexed, it's only a virtual column (expression), and it's not taking up any "space".

Answer (score 4):

The only reason I can think of for having that column is to index it, because there is some common set of read queries that filter on the first few characters in `CD3`.

If the computed column is, indeed, indexed, then the it's valuable because:

- it would required less storage than the full 21 char column
- it would incur less page reads for seeks and scans than an index on the full 21 char column

You mentioned the table is rarely read, but I would check for indexes that use this computed column to be sure.

If it's not indexed, then see [Erik's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/233383/6141) about the storage aspect of non-persisted computed columns.